# How to properly index to an array of changing size due to masking in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, dynamic-arrays

This is a problem I've run into when developing something, and it's a hard question to phrase. So it's best with an simple example:

Imagine you have 4 random number generators which generate an array of size 4:

```
[rng-0,  rng-1,   rng-2,   rng-3]
   |        |        |        | 
[val0,    val1,    val2,    val3]
```

Our goal is to loop through "generations" of arrays populated by these RNGs, and iteratively mask out the RNG which outputted the maximum value.

So an example might be starting out with:
`mask = [False, False, False, False], arr = [0, 10, 1, 3]`, and so we would mask out rng-1.

Then the next iteration could be: `mask = [False, True, False, False], arr = [2, 1, 9]`  (before it gets asked, **yes `arr` HAS to decrease in size with each rng that is masked out**). In this case, it is clear that rng-3 should be masked out (e.g. `mask[3] = True`), but since `arr` is now of different size than `mask`, it is tricky to get the right indexing for setting the mask (since the max of arr is at index 2 of the arr, but the corresponding generator is index 3). This problem grows more an more difficult as more generators get masked out (in my case I'm dealing with a mask of size ~30).

If it helps, here is python version of the example:

```python
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
mask = np.zeros(10, dtype=bool)  # True if generator is being masked
for _ in range(mask.size):
    arr = rng.randint(100, size=~mask.sum())
    unadjusted_max_value_idx = arr.argmax()
    adjusted_max_value_idx = unadjusted_max_value_idx + ????
    mask[adjusted_max_value_idx] = True
```

Any idea a good way to map the index of the max value in the arr to the corresponding index in the mask? (i.e. moving from `unadjusted_max_value_idx` to `adjusted_max_value_idx`)

Comment: Use masked arrays

Comment: I don't really see how masked arrays can be helpful here since each time arr is being reinstantiated (in my actual problem I don't have access to how `arr` is generated, I only feed the mask to an external function, and receive the output)

Comment: Masked arrays maintain a mask and the data separately. You can mask out elements and run a given operation directly.

Comment: Which value are you going to export? The random array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#use a helper list
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
mask = np.zeros(10, dtype=bool)  # True if generator is being masked
ndxLst=list(range(mask.size))
maskHistory=[]
for _ in range(mask.size):
    arr = rng.randint(100, size=(~mask).sum())
    unadjusted_max_value_idx = arr.argmax()
    adjusted_max_value_idx=ndxLst.pop(unadjusted_max_value_idx)
    mask[adjusted_max_value_idx] = True
    maskHistory.append(adjusted_max_value_idx)
print(maskHistory)
print(mask)
```

Comment: WOW! I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now, and man is that solution great. Thank you so much : ).

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you come up with this solution? Is this something you have encountered before or did you just come up with it off the top of your head? (I'm asking since I'm still somewhat new to programming and am looking to better my problem solving skills)

Comment: you are welcome. this is something you will encounter a lot in coding